# Regular Expression to split names into forename/middle name and surname

Tags: regex

Unsure on how to approach this, been trying to figure it out for ages now. I have a whole bunch of names and some will be in different formats to others, one example in particular is say:

**John David Smith** or **John Smith**

Now where possible i would like Regex to pull back two matches one containing the forename (and middle name if it exists) and the other containing surname. Currently i'm using:

```
(^\w+)|(\w+$)
```

which works fine except for the fact that it misses out the middle name(s) if there are any.

I realize i could easy enough split the name out in .net and read it that way but there's a very good reason for using regex which will play a part further down the line in my project.

Thanks

Comment: Use [`^(\w+)(?: (\w+))? (\w+)$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5cw%2b%29%28%3f%3a+%28%5cw%2b%29%29%3f+%28%5cw%2b%29%5cr%3f%24&i=John+David+Smith%0d%0aJohn+Smith&o=m) and grab the middle one in Group 2.

Comment: ([A-Za-z]+),\\s*([A-Za-z]+)\\s*([A-Za-z]+)

Comment: `\w` and `[A-Za-z]` (as suggested by Marker) both will not match my friend's name `Đuro` or his friend `Ćiro`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan [Have you tried before commenting?](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5cw%2b%29%28%3f%3a+%28%5cw%2b%29%29%3f+%28%5cw%2b%29%5cr%3f%24&i=John+David+Smith%0d%0aJohn+Smith%0d%0a%c4%90uro+%d0%92%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80+%c4%86iro&o=m) It is also matching my name, Виктор.

Answer (score 1):

This will return two results.  One will be the first and middle name if it exists, and the second will be the last name.

```
^(.*?)\s([^\s]*)$
```

"John Smith" will return "John" and "Smith", while "John David Smith" will return "John David" and "Smith".  This is making that assumption that names will not contain spaces, but any other character should be fine.

When collecting information like this, you should collect them separately when possible.  This is not a perfect solution when you take last names into account that may include "van der" and other possibilities.  A regular expression has no way to tell if the middle name is two words, or the last name is.